# Best component to control the intensity going through a few LEDs in parallel?

Tags: circuit-design

I'm trying to design a circuit with a potentiometer to control the intensity going through a few LEDs in parallel. I was thinking on using BJT (potentiometer connected to the base) in active region, but as the total intensity going through the collector could get up to 0.5A, the power was getting too close to the maximum power of most BJT I found in mouser. That's why I was thinking that a BJT may not be the ideal component to use here. What other options do I have?
Adding: I want to use the smallest SMD component I can as I don't have much space in my PCB

Comment: "Smallest SMD component" really depends on what the smallest SMD component you can work with is. Can you handle 0.5mm pitch QFP?  DFN?  BGA? XSON?  How much space do you *actually* have for a solution?

Comment: Your question is missing three critical pieces of information.  1) What is the voltage for the LED circuit?  2)  What is the type/color/part number/web page/recommended operating current for the LED?  3) How many LEDs?

Answer (score 1):

Leds use fairly low voltages. If you add a few in series then the maximum current is reduced. Then use PWM to keep the transistor cool.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect Leds in paralell you must add a small resistance (about 200mV drop on R) to each and also use a same type of Leds for proper current balancing.

This parallel group of Leds connect to current limiter or just potentiometer controlled Bjt if you insist.

Find a power transistor in D-pack is not a problem (like 3055). If you choose a suitable voltage source where not much voltage has to be dropped (about 1V) the power loss on Bjt is less than 1W.

Example for potentiometer controlled Bjt: li-ion with 3V at bottom is split into 2.2v on Led, 0.2v on series resistor and 0.6v on transistor.